# if $A.x \le b$, when is $x \le A^{-1}.b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-programming, pseudoinverse

I have a relation, derived from optimality conditions of a linear program:
$$ L \le A.x \le U$$
with:

- $L, U \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$
- $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, with each element $\in \{0,1\}$
- $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

The matrix $A^TA$ is invertible with all eigenvalues $\gt 0$.

Is this last condition sufficient to ensure that the following equation holds:
$$ (A^TA)^{-1}A^TL \le x \le (A^TA)^{-1}A^TU$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $m=n=2$, and $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ This matrix satisfies your conditions.

Take $$ L = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \qquad  x =\begin{pmatrix} -2\\ 2 \end{pmatrix} $$
You have 
$$ L = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \leq  A x =\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 2 \end{pmatrix} $$
but 
$$ A^{-1}L = \begin{pmatrix} -1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \nleq   x =\begin{pmatrix} -2\\ 2 \end{pmatrix} \, . $$

The answer is no.

Comment: Would there any conditions on the matrix $A$ or on the vectors $L,U$ ?

For instance, $L\ge0$ and $U\ge0$ and $\sum_j A_{i,j}=2$ ?

Comment: This is a nice and simple example.

Comment: Well a sufficient condition would be that $A^{-1}$ have entries $\geq 0$. I didn't try to check whether this is a necessary condition though.